# NSManagedObjectContext: Is this a good pattern of thread confinement?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, thread-safety, nsmanagedobjectcontext

With Core Data there's a constant dance around thread safety issues. Executing fetches on one `NSManagedObjectContext` in two different threads guarantees a deadlock. Apple's **Core Data Programming Guide** suggests using thread confinement, but doesn't provide a pattern by which you may accomplish this. I have a quick and dirty solution below:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = objc_getAssociatedObject([NSThread currentThread], _cmd);

    if (!moc && self.persistentStoreCoordinator)
    {
        moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        moc.mergePolicy = NSOverwriteMergePolicy;
        moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
        objc_setAssociatedObject([NSThread currentThread], _cmd, moc, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
    }

    return moc;
}
```

This method would appear in a proprietary class that manages the data stack in my app. It associates a MOC with the current thread. This seems like a plausible solution to me, but it also appears fast and loose.

What should I be worried about attempting a solution like this?

Comment: Have a look at [Grand Central Dispatach](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html). I find it cleaner than dealing with threads directly, and I have had success wrapping calls to my MOC in a dedicated dispatch queue. Based on what you have shown, I don't think there is need to use such runtime functions.

Comment: Also by the way NSThread singletons have a `threadDictionary` you can use to associate objects with a thread. It's safer than messing around with runtime functions :)

Answer (score 1):

You should go the other way around: Use

```
[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:concurrencyType]]
```

to create a context of

- `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` - if you need a context linked to controllers and UI objects that are required to be used only on the main thread, or
- `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` - for a context that runs on a private background queue.

Use `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait` for all operations on the context, this ensures that the operations are executed on the queue specified for the context.

See [Concurrency Support for Managed Object Contexts](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010637-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1) in the "Core Data Release Notes for OS X v10.7 and iOS 5.0" for more information.